# Does Delphi have any equivalent to C's volatile variable?

Tags: c, multithreading, delphi, volatile, memory-model

In C and C++ a variable can be marked as [**volatile**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable), which means the compiler will not optimize it because it may be modified external to the declaring object.  Is there an equivalent in Delphi programming?  If not a keyword, maybe a work around?

My thought was to use **Absolute**, but I wasn't sure, and that may introduce other side effects.

Comment: Absolute introduces an alias, a different name (and possibly type) for the same location.

Comment: If I may ask, why is this needed? Maybe there is another way to do what you need.

Comment: A co-worker was just curious.  I asked him the same thing (why).  I told him what I thought, but that I knew how to find out.

Comment: Your description of what `volatile` means is imprecise at best.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I over simplified my definition. Feel free to elaborate or correct it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Short answer: no.

However, I am not aware of any situation in which the conservative approach of the compiler will change the number of reads or writes if you follow this approach:

When reading a cross-thread visible location, save its value to a local before doing any further manipulation; similarly, restrict writes to a single assignment.

The Delphi compiler does not perform common subexpression elimination (CSE) on non-local location expressions when there are calls to non-inlined methods between the expressions, as the compiler doesn't do interprocedural optimization and thus it would not be correct even for single-threaded code.

So, you may want to use InterlockedExchange() to do your reads and writes to force this; additionally, this will cause a full memory barrier, so the processor won't reorder reads and writes either.

Answer (score 14):

According to [The Delphi Language for Mobile Development](https://www.embarcadero.com/white-papers/category/3-white-papers-application-development?download=102%3Athe-delphi-language-for-mobile-development) whitepaper, Delphi's mobile compilers have supported a [`[volatile]`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Compiler_Attributes#Volatile) attribute since they were first introduced:

> The `volatile` attribute is used to mark fields that are subject to change by different threads, so that code generation does not optimize copying the value in a register or another temporary memory location.
>
> You can use the `volatile` attribute to mark the following declarations:
>
> - Variables (global and local)
> - Parameters
> - Fields of a record or a class.
>
> You cannot use the volatile attribute to mark the following declarations:
>
> - Type
> - Procedures, Functions or Methods
> - Expressions
>
> ```
> type
>   TMyClass = class
>   private
>     [volatile] FMyVariable: TMyType;
>   end;
> ```

Starting with Delphi 10.1 Berlin, the desktop compilers now support `[volatile]` as well.

[Attributes Supported by All Compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/What%27s_New#Attributes_Supported_by_All_Compilers)

> Now, all Delphi compilers support the following attributes:
>
> - [unsafe](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Compiler_Attributes#Unsafe)
> - [volatile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Compiler_Attributes#Volatile)
> - [weak](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Compiler_Attributes#Weak)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any equivalent, nor do I think that the **absolute** directive will help you. **absolute** allows you to have two variables that use the same address, but I do not think it will prevent the compiler from optimising references to that memory.

I imagine you could use a pointer and manage it yourself. That way whatever the compiler does as far as optimising retrival of the pointer value, it should not assume the value stored at the address is the same as last time it read it, but this is pure speculation.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi for .Net does not have the keyword either, but the .Net platform has util functions for it. See [Thread.VolatileRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.volatileread.aspx) and [Thread.VolatileWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.volatilewrite.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamically allocated pointers?

```
var
  MyVarPtr: ^integer;
begin
  New(MyVarPtr);
  MyVarPtr^ := 5;
...
```

This should keep the compiler from using a register for the integer value (but it might still use one for the address). I am not sure how that compares to volatile, though.