# Weird code execution: Execution starts in the middle of the while loop

Tags: delphi

I have a thread. When this thread is executed, an infinite while loop starts, which reads class' member variable.

Odd thing is, that everything is fine to certain point, where while loop starts execution in the middle.

Code:

```
procedure MyThread.Execute;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  NameThreadForDebugging('MyThread');

  while True do
  begin
    if (PrevLine1 <> CurLine1) and (PrevLine2 <> CurLine2) then
    begin

      {some code}

      PrevLine1 := CurLine1;   //<-- The place where execution starts...
      PrevLine2 := CurLine2;

      {some code}
    end;
    Sleep(500);
  end;

  self.Terminate;
  self.Destroy;
end;
```

I could place breakpoints EVERYWHERE in this procedure, but it stops at

```
PrevLine1 := CurLine1;   //<-- The place where execution starts...
```

CurLine1 is private member which can be changed via object property.
It all works fine, but just one time the faulty behavior occurs.

Has anyone faced something similar or knows what steps to take in order to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have two versions of the file in question, one that is found by the IDE (looks at search path first) and the other found by the compiler (looks at source path of project first). This happens quite often in Delphi 2007 when you have several trees checkout at the same time. Another thing that might help is a build all.

Comment: you might find interesting the question [Does Delphi have any equivalent to C's volatile variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232075/does-delphi-have-any-equivalent-to-cs-volatile-variable)

Comment: @Nick I'm not sure what C `volatile` has to do with threading?

Comment: @David: `volatile` protects the variables from compiler's optimizations and threading can be affected from that. So I posted it as related to this question.

Comment: @Nick C `volatile` doesn't make a variable atomic, which is a common misunderstanding. It's very difficult to see how it relates to this question.

Comment: @David: it isn't about atomic operations. For example a *smart* compiler may transform `if (foo==true)` into `if (true)` if `foo` isn't declared as `volatile`.

Comment: @David: <bad_joke> I'm not Nick C, I'm Nick D </bad_joke>

Comment: @Nick You'll have to say more about `foo` for that comment to have any weight

Comment: @David: come on, I have experienced such bugs. I was polling the state of a shared `int` variable in a `while (...)` to break the loop. Well, the compiler had transformed the code into an infinite loop, like the example I posted above. Of course, now I use OS objects to sync threads.

Comment: @Nick Well, `volatile` isn't the fix, atomics or locks are.

Comment: @David: `volatile` did fix the bug in my case because the compiler didn't optimize the code. Anyway, now I use OS atomic or lock mechanisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i got it work now! 
One member who post his answer suggested me to remove all the code from Execute method and start putting it back with little pieces. Unfortunately he removed his answer and i can't remember his name.

Problem was, that i used CPortLib component (TComPort) in my execute code. I then opened and closed connection in my while loop and at some point it skipped code (nothing to do with if/else or smth).

Weird still, that it skipped code like that!
Thank you everybody who tried to help. I appreciate that!

Answer (score 3):

My guess: You're debugging with `Optimization=True`. Turn Optimization off, do a rebuild, try again.

This is very likely since the default "Debug" profile in Delphi 2010 has Optimization=True.

Answer (score 2):

If there are any unused statements in the procedure, then Delphi compiler will automatically eliminate those statements. Its actually a good compiler feature

Comment: Yes, but it works. Just sometimes it doesn't or acts like i described and after that everything is just normal.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are compiling the right unit, try adding some trash in there, can you still compile? are the available breakpoints positioned on the right position?

what code do you have in the `{some code}` section ? is it an if statement which results false all the time?

Answer (score 1):

Where are you initializing PrevLine1, PrevLine2, CurLine1, and CurLine2? If they're initially set to different values before Execute is called, the compiler might be optimizing out the first conditional test because it can tell it will always be true.

```
PrevLine1 := 1;
PrevLine2 := 1;
CurLine1 := 2;
CurLine2 := 2;

// The next line never has to execute on the first pass
// through the loop, as the test will always be true at
// this point.
if (PrevLine1 <> CurLine1) and (PrevLine2) <> (CurLine2) then
begin
  ..
end;
```

Turn off optimization, as others have said, or look at the assembly code generated in the CPU window starting with the first line after `NameThreadForDebugging`. Then see if the breakpoint at the first loop test is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this artificial debug-break instruction at the first line of the method:

```
asm
 int 3
end;
```

Then run, watch it break, open the CPU view and see if there is any code generated for the `NameThreadForDebugging` call.

--jeroen

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem with a unit. The reason was that special non printable characters were in the file (eg Formfeed). Made a ctrl+C then ctrl+v in a new unit and saved it in place of the previous and everything went fine.